# Dynamic path in Ransack search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am using Ransack for my search forms, which work great. The search form looks like this:

```
.table-actions
  .search
    = search_form_for [:admin, search] do |f|
      .field
        = f.text_field :name_cont, placeholder: I18n.t(".general.search")
      .actions= f.submit I18n.t(".general.search_button")
  .add-record
    %button= link_to I18n.t(".general.table.add"), new_admin_plan_path
```

Now I want to move this search form to a partial, so it can be reused on several pages, some within namespace `admin`, others not.
So I created a partial where the `search_form_for` looks like this:

```
= search_form_for path do |f|
```

And I want to call it like this:

```
= render "shared/table_actions", search: @search, path: ??
```

What should path have as dynamic value to make this work? Or is there better solution?

Comment: Have you put just `= search_form_for path do |f|` in your newly created partial? Can you post the complete partial? if this is not the case. And, what's `@search` for? where are you using it in your partial?

Comment: The search form in the partial is exactly the same as above, except that ``[:admin, search]`` is replaced with ``path`` to make it dynamic. @search is Ransack's search object.

Comment: I still didn't understand your question. Help me little bit to understand your situation. Are you saying how you can pass `path: ??` `locals` to `shared/table_actions` partial?

Comment: That's right and especially in the case of a namespaced path

Comment: So why can't you just do: `= render "shared/table_actions", search: @search, path: @path` and set the path variable in controller?

Comment: Not in the case of a namespaced route like ``[:admin, :search]`` as far as I know

Comment: you can do something like: `@path = url_for([:admin, :search])` and this should work, as far as I know. :)

Answer (score 1):

It might be late, but here's the solution that does work:

let's say we have 2 actions in `clients_controller`:

```
  def index
    @ransack_clients = Client.ransack(params[:clients_search], search_key: :clients_search)
    @clients = @ransack_clients.result.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15).order("created_at DESC")
    @ransack_path = clients_path
  end

  def bday_today
    @ransack_clients = Client.bday_today.search(params[:clients_search], search_key: :clients_search)
    @clients = @ransack_clients.result.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15).order("created_at DESC")
    @ransack_path = bday_today_clients_path
    render 'index'
  end
```

notice the `@ransack_path`.

Now, in the index view the `ransack_path` is set automatically, so that when you press submit, your search is performed in the current controller!

```
= search_form_for @ransack_clients, as: :clients_search, url: @ransack_path do |f|
```

Here's a piece of my routes:

```
  resources :clients do
    get :bday_today, on: :collection
    collection do
      match 'search' => 'clients#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
    end
  end
```

### 2021 update:

just use `request.path` in the form builder